# Need to "pivot" a SQL query in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with ID's for customer roles and the name of the role:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Guest |
| 2 | Registered |

And another table with Customer ID's and their related roles

| ID | Customer_Id | CustomerRole_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 4 | 2 |

The two tables are linked on Table_1.Id = Table_2.CustomerRole_Id. I want my query to return a result like this:

| Customer_Id | Name_Guest | Name_Registered |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Guest | Registered |
| 2 | Guest | Registered |
| 3 | Guest |  |
| 4 |  | Registered |

My current output looks like this, and I want the Name column to be rows instead, so that there is only 1 row per Customer_Id

| Customer_Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Guest |
| 1 | Registered |
| 2 | Guest |
| 2 | Registered |
| 3 | Guest |
| 4 | Registered |

Comment: Have you tried CROSSTAB query? Access has a wizard for that. Also review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html. Your desired output doesn't really make sense. You want the words "Guest" and "Registered" under columns "Guest" and "Registered"?

Comment: I want to be able to view all the customer roles for each customer ID. In the second table you can see that Customer_Id "1" has 2 rows for 2 different CustomerRole_Id's. I want to display the Customer_Id with the "Name" of every CustomerRole_Id it has.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and your query does that. Doesn't change my comment. Consider http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Comment: Are you able to include a screen shot of what you want your desired output to look like?